# A problem in limits

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am solving problems in Limits and stuck in this problem.

**Problem**

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a positive decreasing function with  $$\large{\lim \limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(\frac{x-x^{3}}{6} )}{f(x)} =1}$$, then find $\large{\lim \limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(\sin x)}{f(x)}}$.

**My Try**

I'm not getting any idea on how to begin. 
It's given in the question that $f:R\rightarrow R$ is a positive decreasing function.

i.e. $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$.

But how to use this information in solving this problem.

Any hint will be of great help.
Please do not provide complete solution.

Comment: Do you mean to take the limit $x\to0$ instead of $x\to\infty$?

Comment: @BarryCipra No, It's limit $x \to\infty$.

Comment: But the problem doesn't make sense for $x\to\infty$.  The first limit cannot be $1$ if $f$ is a positive decreasing function, since the numerator, being the function evaluated at negative numbers, is necessarily larger (and larger) than the denominator.

Comment: @BarryCipra I guess this problem is based on Sandwich Theorem. $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(\frac{x-x^{3}}{6} )}{f(x)} =1$and $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(x)}{f(x)} =1$. and $f(\frac{x-x^{3}}{6})>f(x)$. But I do get your point.

Comment: Note that $f(x^3-x/6) \to \sup f$, and $f(x) \to \inf f \ge 0$. So you have that $\inf f = \sup f$, hence the function must be constant.

Comment: @Crostul Yeah! And hence $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{f(\sin x)}{f(x)}$ must be equal to $1$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Crostul, I agree that a constant function would work if you interpret "decreasing" as "non-increasing," but note that the OP specifies $f'(x)\lt0$.